# Clickable button inside of a clickable panel

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a button inside of an accordion, like this:

[image]

I made the entire accordion head clickable by doing this:

```
<accordion-heading ng-click="isopen=!isopen">
    <div>
        <span class="accordion-header">
            <i class="pull-right glyphicon"
               ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-down': accordionOpen,
               'glyphicon-chevron-right': !accordionOpen}"></i>
        </span>
        <button class="delete-button" ng-click="remove()">Delete</button>
    </div>
</accordion-heading>
```

The problem I have is when I click the delete button, remove() is called AND the accordion open/closes.

Is there a way to stop the accordion header from opening/closing when I click the delete button?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `$event.preventDefault(); $event.stopPropagation();`:

```
<button class="delete-button" ng-click="
  $event.preventDefault(); $event.stopPropagation(); remove()">Delete</button>
```

The click event object is accessible in ng-click as `$event`. [preventDefault](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.preventDefault) and [stopPropagation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.stopPropagation) will stop the event from reaching the accordion-heading click handler.

Answer (score 4):

You need to stop the event from bubbling to the container

```
$scope.remove = function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopPropagation();
  ...
}
```

and

```
<button class="delete-button" ng-click="remove($event)">Delete</button>
```

Demo: [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/EOCSakTVRCThnOEJXBuJ?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

For me, if I use both functions

```
$event.preventDefault();
$event.stopPropagation();
```

nothing happened at all. So I use only

```
 $event.stopPropagation();
```

It works good.